# Data, which is bound through string interpolation, doesn't update in real time, in angular4

Tags: angular, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor. Every time, I type something in the editor, it fires an event `onEditorKeyup` which fires the method `keyupHandlerFunction($event)`. Its implementation is as follows:

**app.component.html**

```
<simple-tiny
  [elementId]="'my-editor-id'"
  (onEditorKeyup)="keyupHandlerFunction($event)"
>
</simple-tiny>
<br>

<div>{{blogContent}}</div> <!--=====Line 1: Doesn't show anything ==-->

<br>

<button (click)="doSomething()"> click me!</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

      title = 'app';
      blogContent;

      keyupHandlerFunction(event){

        this.blogContent=event;
        console.log(this.blogContent);//=================Line2: work fine ==================
      }

      doSomething(){
        console.log(this.blogContent);
      }
    }
```

Now:

1. **Line 1 doesn't display anything at all.  Ideally, it should display
   the content of editor as I type.**
2. Line 2 works perfectly fine. It logs, what I type, in real time
3. If I click the button, Line 1 displays the content. Which is weird, since button's listener doesn't anything except logging the content.

I don't think it's the problem with TinyMCE since Line 2 logs does work fine.

[image]

Edit: adding tinyMCE component: simple-tiny-component.component.ts

**simple-tiny-component.component.ts**

```
import {
  Component,
  OnDestroy,
  AfterViewInit,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  Output
} from '@angular/core';

declare var tinymce: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'simple-tiny',
  template: `<textarea id="{{elementId}}"></textarea>`
})
export class SimpleTinyComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() elementId: String;
  @Output() onEditorKeyup = new EventEmitter<any>();

  editor;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#' + this.elementId,
      plugins: ['link', 'paste', 'table'],
      skin_url: 'assets/skins/lightgray',
      setup: editor => {
        this.editor = editor;
        editor.on('keyup', () => {
          const content = editor.getContent();
          this.onEditorKeyup.emit(content);
        });
      },
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    tinymce.remove(this.editor);
  }
}
```

Comment: This may be due to your data not being two-way binded or a life-cycle hook issue. Have you tried using `[(ngModel)]` yet?

Comment: @yoonjesung Thanks for suggestion but ngModel will just give the textarea's text content. I am looking for text in html format. If I was looking just for text, I won't be using WYSIWYG.

Comment: put       blogContent="aaa" in app.component to test if it show at the start

Comment: @Vega This is a unique ID required by TinyMCE. I actually copied this entire code from their website. https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angular2/

Comment: @Vega Yes, it does

Comment: do you have simple-tiny code exactly the same as in the link? and

Comment: @Vega Yes, its almost the same

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I think the issue is the WYSIWYG is generating html, but you can't really display html the way you are trying:

```
<div [innerHTML]="blogContent"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Also try doing this inside your function: 

import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
constructor(private ref : ChangeDetectorRef){}

and inside your function call: 
ref.detectChanges();

Comment: Hi kevin, ref.detectChanges() works perfect! Thank you and +1. This will get me going. However, I would still like to know what is the problem with my current code.

Comment: No problem, feel free to accept the answer :) I think that the issue is your changed value is coming from another component, and that component is outside of the zone of this component so it's not detecting the change. In my mind it's a bug that angular can hopefully fix in later versions.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing some research for this, and following is what I think:
It is important to understand when Angular triggers the data change detection (CD) . [This is a good article about the topic.](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html#whats-change-detection-anyways)

> Which brings us to the conclusion that, basically whenever some asynchronous operation has been performed, our application state might have changed. This is when someone needs to tell Angular to update the view.

However, if CD happens to start at all async events (keypress, mousemove), it would be inefficient. This is where zones come into the picture. Angular zone will trigger CD all async operation inside of it but not for ones outside of it.

1. **"Line 1 doesn't display anything at all. Ideally, it should display the content of editor as I type."** This is because the async callback which has triggered the event `onEditorKeyup` has not been called by Angular but TinyMCE. Therefore, Angular change detection doesn't run when `onEditorKeyup` is triggered.
2. "If I click the button, Line 1 displays the content. Which is weird, since button's listener doesn't anything except logging the content.". This is because when the button is clicked its listener is fired by angular causing change detection to trigger. And hence the resultant update in the view.

I am still bit fuzzy about zone and CD. I will keep this answer updates as my understanding evolves.